# How can I acces to CLI on a router?

Tags: router, cli

I'm studying Telecomunications Engineering and I know how to configurate routers using the command line interface (I've done lots of simulations). My problem is that I'm trying to configurate 2 routers TP-LINK and I don't know how to access to the CLI. How can someone access to a router CLI using linux?

Comment: Many SOHO routers (and few enterprise ones) don't have a CLI interface. Note that consumer grade devices are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly note that there is no standard for router CLIs. It varies both between brands and sometimes between product lines within a brand.

Secondly note that home/small buisness routers may not have a CLI at all or at least may not have a documented CLI.

As for actually accessing the CLI you can either use a serial cable with a serial console application or a network protocol like ssh or telnet. If the device has a documented CLI then the manufacturer should tell you how to access it.